# How can I configure Outlook.com new message keyboard shortcut?

Tags: outlook.com, office-365

The Outlook/Live/Hotmail keyboard for Create new message is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>... this always opens a new instance of my browser. This is not what I want and means I can't avoid the need to keep on reaching for the mouse.

How can I configure things so that I have a shortcut that lets me Create a new message in Outlook/Live/Hotmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full list of the [keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/keyboard-shortcuts) for Outlook.com, and you could change the default shortcuts to the ones from Yahoo! or Gmail from the settings:

[image: outlook.com keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. I know I can change the mode as per the screenshot. But I've learned the Outlook shortcuts... the Create new message is just a badly chosen shortcut choice, so presumably there must be some mechanism for "fixing" it to something like Ctrl+Shift+N

Comment: @SimonMartin yes.. Microsoft did it wrong again :) On a Mac it works of course.. since Cmd+N is the shortcut for new window.. One solution is to use the Gmail shortcuts and then just use `C` to create new mail.. (for more http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594)

Comment: I don't use GMail, so that would mean learning a whole lot of new shortcuts. Grr, how could no one have noticed Ctrl+N just opens a new window before...?

Comment: @SimonMartin I'm sure they'll fix that.. But send feedback to point that out..! It's pretty _stupid_ to have it like that..